# Socat virtual serial port not recognized

Tags: virtual-serial-port, socat

I'm using socat to create a couple virtual serial ports.  One I connect to with a simple C program (using termios), and the other I'd like to connect to using a program called Ardupilot Mega Planner (for RC stuff).  However, the Planner does not recognize the virtual port (listed under /dev/pts), only the tty devices and /dev/serial devices.  Do I need to do some sort of special mount for this to work?  Or is there a workaround I could try?  I tried "linking" an existing serial port (ttyS0, for example), but I'm getting an "inappropriate ioctl" error if I try anything of the kind (virtual port to real port, real port to real port).  Any ideas?

edit:  After viewing the source code for the program (Mission Planner), it seems that it only "recognizes" (or adds the ports of) all the /dev/ttyS* devices, the /dev/serial/by-id/* devices, /dev/USB0, and /dev/ACM0.  So either I need to edit the source code or find a way to "validate" a ttyS* port.  It still appears that the Mission Planner just won't connect to any ttyS* devices other than S1 or S0.  Any ideas?  I have a feeling it's because they're not configured correctly, somehow.

edit 2:  I finally got a hold of the ArdupilotMega Planner source code and changed it so that it includes devices from /dev/pts/.  However, I'm still getting the same problem.  The Planner gets some sort of problem when it opens the port.  Is there some setting that needs to be checked/changed right off the bat for a program to be able to connect to it?  Going to research and try to understand serial port communication more thoroughly...

Answer (score 2):

Right, just found I couldn't comment on my answer since I didn't have an account. Anyway, try this command:

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS10 PTY,link=/dev/ttyS11
```

and link your programs to ttyS10 and ttyS11.

Comment: Alright, tried that now.  My program (APM Mission Planner) still doesn't seem to recognize any serial port that socat links.  I wasn't able to connect to ttyS10, though I used the exact command you gave above (though I had to use it like so:  `socat -d -d PTY,link=/dev/ttyS10 PTY,link=/dev/ttyS11`.  Otherwise the window will just freeze if I don't put the "-d -d" in.  Anyways, I don't know what it is that socat does, but the program doesn't seem to like it.  Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: Also: The Mission Planner doesn't seem to want to connect to ttyS10, period, even if socat isn't doing anything (normally it will try to connect to ports it recognizes, even if nothing is plugged into them/connected to them). So I don't know if this is a problem with socat as much as it is my system not recognizing ttyS10 and/or ttyS11 (though termios seems to accept them just fine).

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what's causing this problem. Everything about the socat command is fine. I guess it's something to with the APM mission planner program.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem and solved it with sending the serial stuff over tcp:

```
socat tcp-l:5760 /dev/YOURPORT,raw,echo=0,bHEREBAUDRATE
```

Then in Misson planner choose "TCP", Server: 127.0.0.1, Port: 5760

I can successfully connect in this way to an emulated serial port.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried linking to higher ttyS's, for example ttyS10 or higher. These are not usually assigned to anything.
EDIT: Also what command are you using to create the serial ports

Comment: Alright, here's the command I used to make the virtual ports:

`sudo socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyS10,raw,echo=0`

Then I try to connect to it with my program, and it throws an I/O exception (something about an invalid argument).  Sorry for being a serial device newbie, but do I need to mount that port or anything?

Comment: I fear the SerialPort object is not able to be used with socat virtual com ports (invalid argument exception). I will switch my code to filestream and see if that works.