# Linux Virtual Serial Port Not Showing Up In List

Tags: linux, node.js, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

None of the solutions from this similar problem help: [Socat virtual serial port not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634725/socat-virtual-serial-port-not-recognized)

I'm creating a virtual serial port using socat and then linking it properly, but node-serialport is not picking it up.

```
$ sudo socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS10 pty,raw,echo=0,link=/dev/ttyS11
2015/09/01 01:36:44 socat[22927] N PTY is /dev/pts/9
2015/09/01 01:36:44 socat[22927] N PTY is /dev/pts/10
2015/09/01 01:36:44 socat[22927] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

In node using [node-serialport](https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport#list-ports):

```
$ cat test.js 
var serialPort = require("serialport");
serialPort.list(function (err, ports) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  ports.forEach(function(port) {
    console.log(port.comName);
    console.log(port.pnpId);
    console.log(port.manufacturer);
  });
});
$ node test.js 
{ [Error: ENOENT, scandir '/dev/serial/by-id'] errno: -2, code: 'ENOENT', path: '/dev/serial/by-id' }
```

You'll notice that no serial port is being picked up. What can I do to be able to list this port?